# How to print several lines of text made by a user built function in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm creating a shiny app but I'm having problems getting the text output of a function I made which prints several lines of text.
The function is this one:

```
summary_library=function(taxon19){
  print(paste("Number of specimens with A grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="A")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="A"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"))
  print(paste("Number of specimens with B grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="B")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="B"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"))
  print(paste("Number of specimens with C grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="C")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="C"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"))
  print(paste("Number of specimens with D grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="D")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="D"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"))
  print(paste("Number of specimens with E grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="E")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="E"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"))
  print(paste("Number of different species:",length(unique(taxon19$species))))
  print(paste("Number of different BIN numbers:",length(unique(taxon19$BIN))))
  print(paste("Number of different collectors:",length(unique(taxon19$collectors))))
  print(paste("Number of different countries:",length(unique(taxon19$country))))
  print(paste("Total Number of specimens in reference library:",length(taxon19$species)))
}
summary_library(taxon19)
```

taxon19 is a dataset that is created inside the shiny app but I'm not being able to create a viable output for this function.
It prints something like this:

```
[1] "Number of specimens with A grade: 57   Percentage: 64.8 %"
[1] "Number of specimens with B grade: 8   Percentage: 9.09 %"
[1] "Number of specimens with C grade: 0   Percentage: 0 %"
[1] "Number of specimens with D grade: 23   Percentage: 26.1 %"
[1] "Number of specimens with E grade: 0   Percentage: 0 %"
[1] "Number of different species: 23"
[1] "Number of different BIN numbers: 21"
[1] "Number of different collectors: 23"
[1] "Number of different countries: 7"
[1] "Total Number of specimens in reference library: 88"
```

How can I make all these lines appear as output?
Thanks in advance for any responses

Comment: Do you want each of the whole lines, including the 'Number of...' text to be in the output, or just the numbers? Either way, I'm guessing at the beginning of the function you'll want to initialize a vector `output<-c()` and then assign each line to an element of `output`, then put `return(output)` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if I understood you right, you should do two things:

First, make summary_library return ONE vector or list, instead of using print(), which shiny will output to the console by default (unless you render it, which would be bad practice). Something like

```
summary_library <- function(taxon19){ 
    out <- paste(
        paste(...), 
        paste(...),
        ...
    , sep = "\n") 
}
```

Second, define an `textOutput("myText")` in the Shiny UI and render it on the server side with `output$myText <- renderText({ summary_library })`.

See [Shiny Documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderText.html)

Comment: alright I think that's gonna work, thanks. but do I ever use the "out" vector I create inside the function?

Comment: `out` is returned to the parent frame (`summary_library `) so you can render that one

Comment: thanks it worked but the thing is that the text isn't separated in different lines, i tried collapse="\n" but it didn't work as well

Comment: consider going for `uiOutput` and `renderUI()` and use `tagList(tags$p("..."), tags$p("..."))` instead.